# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in grails

Tags: java, grails

I am using grails to run https://github.com/Netflix/ice but I am just not able to get the server running, I get the following error:

| Error 2014-06-06 14:52:55,978 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Message: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    Line | Method

I added this to my .bashrc file and it does not help:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Xmx1024M -server"
```

Comment: Where is .bashrc file located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set the `MaxPermSize` to the same as the max heap size?

Try:

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -server"
```

and let the JVM automatically set the perm size for you.  If you find that is not sufficient, you can start tuning it.

Comment: Amir I tried that, but still the same `| Error 2014-06-06 15:07:11,263 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Message: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
`

Comment: Try 2g for Xms and Xmx

Comment: It would also be nice if you could confirm that the process is actually honoring these values

Comment: Amir, thanks a lot for your help, it is honoring and making it 2g worked.

Comment: Where is .bashrc file located

Comment: `.bashrc` is the hidden file. Go to home folder of your linux directory, press `Ctrl+H` and you can see the file there.